# count voting for different surveys

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Well i have table called surveys containing data and column in following manner. The data is collected by feedback of people. each survey contains max 20 options.

```
form   Survey1  survery2  survey3 survey4 survey5 survey6  
1         16       1         2       5        11      9
2         9        6         16      5        11      9
3         8        3         2       5        11      9
4         16       1         2       5        11      9
5         16       6         4       5        11      9
6         15       1         2       5        11      9
7         16       1         2       5        11      9
8         15       1         16      5        11      9
.
.
.
```

so on

each survey have option 1 to 16
i need an out put like

survey 1

```
forms      options
 4           16
 2           15
 1            8
 1            9
```

survey 2

```
forms      options
 5            1
 2            6
 1            3
.
.
.
.
```

till 6 survey . I need all six survey records at once . I am using Sql server.

Comment: What is the rule in obtaining the table underneath Survey? How are you getting that value? For example, row 1 of Survey 1 that you posted you have Forms,options as 4,16. What is 4 and what is 16 here?

Comment: OK. It looks like you're just trying to get a COUNT of each answer for each survey. This isn't hard. What have you tried?

Comment: I'm a little confused by the table structure you've outlined here.  Is the idea that there is a table containing 7 columns - a form, and then the 6 survey columns with each survey column containing a number between 1-16, and that there will be 20 records in the table?

Comment: every survey have 16 to 20 options and each form have 7 value showing in first table called Surveys

in output the 4 is the count and 16 is the option . people select option 16 max times and the count is 4.

Comment: @mks - I think we are missing some tables here.  There doesn't appear to be enough information in the one table you outlined to provide the 3 pieces of data, and you seem to be making reference to another table in your comment.

Comment: no this is all data and i need counts of option that most selecting in all six surveys in a form shown in out put 

@ZLK

Comment: @Momus No this is all data and i need counts of option that most selecting in all six surveys separately in a form shown in out put 

 yes you are right but i need it in one query . Currently i am able to achieve it by writing 6 different quires but i need only query.

select Top 5 count(a.Survey1) as "Forms" ,a.surveys as "option" from surveys  a order by count(a.Survey1)  Desc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright... I'm not sure I understand what you really want, but based on what you've described I'm going to take a stab at it...

```
(select 'survey1' as survey, survey1 as forms, count(*) as options from some_table
group by survey, survey1 order by options desc)

union all

(select 'survey2' as survey, survey2 as forms, count(*) as options from some_table
group by survey, survey2 order by options desc)

union all

(select 'survey3' as survey, survey3 as forms, count(*) as options from some_table
group by survey, survey3 order by options desc)

union all

(select 'survey4' as survey, survey4 as forms, count(*) as options from some_table
group by survey, survey4 order by options desc)

union all

(select 'survey5' as survey, survey5 as forms, count(*) as options from some_table
group by survey, survey5 order by options desc)

union all

(select 'survey6' as survey, survey6 as forms, count(*) as options from some_table
group by survey, survey6 order by options desc)
```

This will return a single set of results with the option, and the number of times it appeared in the column for a specific survey.  I added a column to be able to tell which results are coming from which survey.

Comment: thanks it solve my problem. it is working by removing order by from each sub query .

Comment: the order by clause is not working if a remove the query works fine but providing wrong data

Comment: Provide the SQL with the changes you have made to it.

Comment: in count (*) i change it to count(severy1) then it work fine